# CSS border won't animate

Tags: css, less, css-animations

For some reason, when I hover over the div, the border animates properly, but mousing off of it produces no transition. What am I missing?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbPbvr

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
  Test
</div>
```

LESS:

```
.test {
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: none;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: border 100ms ease-out;

  &:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    transition: border 100ms ease-out;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you truly want no border, you can animate the color to transparent and the length to 0:

```css
.test {
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: border 100ms ease-out;
}

.test:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  Test
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't animate to border-bottom: none, change that to border-bottom: RGBA(0,0,0,0) (or perhaps border-bottom: transparent if that works).

You also don't need "transition: border 100ms ease-out" in the hover scope.

Answer (score 1):

Border can't be `none`. Try this:

```
.test {
  background: #eee;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: border 100ms ease-out;

  &:hover {
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    transition: border 100ms ease-out;
  }
}
```